# Excel switch statement formula to convert "M" or "K" to 1000000000 or 1000000

Tags: excel, switch-statement, formula

I have a data set with the estimated worth of soccer players. When I downloaded the set, all of the net-worth's looked like the following:

```
85.5M
30.3K
20M
```

I want to create a switch statement that would automatically go through the data to convert the M's and the K's appropriately, example:

```
85,500,000,000
30,300,000
20,000,000,000
```

The problem seems to be with the `(LEFT(H3, -3)`, part of the formula because that is where I am getting red braces. I've tried switching`LEFT` to `RIGHT` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
=SWITCH(LEFT(H3, -3), "M", 1000000000, "K", 1000000)
```

The results look like `#VALUE` which I have looked into and have come to the conclusion its a syntax error...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting the column to a number? This may be a custom number format - I use them at work. I doubt it's that simple, but worth a shot

Comment: Unfortunatly, it looks like your `Left(Range, 3)` won't work because not all of the outputs have the same char length. `85.5` = `Len(4)` while `20` = `Len(2)`

Comment: In your function:  `LEFT(H3, -3)`, the number of characters argument cannot be a negative number.  Hence your `#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All 3 solutions produce the same result shown in photo. The macro allows you to overwrite the values in the cell so you won't need a helper column*

[image]

---

### If you are open to a helper column....

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="M",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"M","")*10^6,SUBSTITUTE(A2,"K","")*10^3)
```

---

### If you are open to Macro....

```
Option Explicit

Sub Convert()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- UPDATE

Dim LR As Long, Val As Range
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Change .Offset(, 4) to .Offset(,) to replace the existing value
For Each Val In Range("A2:A" & LR)
    Select Case Right(Val, 1)
        Case "M"
            Val.Offset(, 4) = Left(Val, Len(Val) - 1) * (10 ^ 6)
        Case "K"
            Val.Offset(, 4) = Left(Val, Len(Val) - 1) * (10 ^ 3)
    End Select
Next Val

End Sub
```

---

### If you are open to UDF....

```
Function CSTConvert(Val As Range) As Long

Select Case Right(Val, 1)
    Case "M"
        CSTConvert = Left(Val, Len(Val) - 1) * (10 ^ 6)
    Case "K"
        CSTConvert = Left(Val, Len(Val) - 1) * (10 ^ 3)
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: This (formula version, havn't checked he VBA) is vulnerable to two things: it's case sensitive, and fails on no training "K" or "M" (I know, the OP didn't specify these possibilities, but just saying...) That said, it might be a good thing to be case sensitive, after all `M` = 10^6 `m` = 10^-3

Comment: Good call out @chrisneilsen. If that is the situation, OP, nest the RIGHT portion of range in the function UPPER to convert lower case accordingly

Comment: For the macro, just add the lower case to the case as a comma separated value (Case “M”, “m”)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and @Michael Burton helped out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
 =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*SWITCH(RIGHT(A1,1),"M",10^6,"K",10^3),A1)
```

Comment: What error are you anticipating? +1 - i've never seen the `SWITCH` function up until now so wanting to understand the error part

Comment: @urdearboy `SWITCH` will return an error if `RIGHT(A1,1)` is not one of the listed options. So, in that case, return the original value instead of the numeric portion `*` the multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use right().  Right returns last character (or characters) or a string.  Using it, there are a few solutions.

You could do

```
Iferror(Value(A1),Value(Left(A1,Len(A1)-1))*If(right(A1)="M",10^6,10^3))
```

What we're doing is first saying if Value of A1 is an error, evaulate the function.  This is because if Value A1 is simply a number, it will ignore all the string nonsense we plan on doing to it.

Assuming it is not a number, there must be a K or M at the end.  We want to remove this to get the number.  Therefore, we take the leftmost characters up to the K or M and only look at those.  We do this by asking what the length of A1 is, and pulling 1 fewer characters from the left.  This will always leave the last character out, which in our case will always be the K or M.  It is important we filtered out the numbers before doing this otherwise it would remove the final number and our result would be off by a factor of 10.

Now we evaluate this string to get a number.  We now need to multiply it by the K or M we pulled off.  Luckily, this is as simple as putting a * and an if statement since we only have 2 options.  Either it is an M and we multiply by 10^6, or it is a k and we multiply by 10^3.

But because it's excel, there's also a lot of bullshit you can pull:

```
Iferror(Value(A1),(Left(A1,Len(A1)-1)+0)*If(right(A1)="M",10^6,10^3))
```

is technically shorter and will still work despite making less sense.